# Does Sodium Precipitate with anything to find the level when titrating?

Tags: titration, precipitation

I am trying to find sodium in animal feeds. I already have a procedure to find chloride by using Mercuric Nitrate to form Mercuric Chloride using a titration method but am having a difficult time finding a procedure to precipitate Sodium with another element using a titration method. I know I could reverse calculate to Salt and then Sodium but with animal feeds there can be more than just salt sodium in the sample. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason not to use analytical instrumentation, e.g., atomic absorption spectroscopy or ion selective electrodes? I know titration is well-loved, but sodium compounds are usually soluble.

Comment: See https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is-there-any-method-for-determination-of-sulfate-sodium-by-titration for some suggestions on insoluble sodium compounds, though, as mentioned, this is not done routinely because of lack of specificity, expense, etc.

Comment: Mercury chloride isn't a good choice either. It's not the healthiest of options and it's quite soluble (in water). Why not use silver nitrate?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Very interesting link to insoluble sodium compounds. Personally, I have always avoided the crown ethers because of the testicular atrophy issue. The sodium zinc uranyl acetate compound is neat: the uranyl ions could be detected subsequently via fluorescence.

Comment: Ed V, I did not know crown ethers were so horrible. Thankfully, I don't belong to the era when uranium salts were used to precipitate sodium in all standard labs :-) This test is to be found in most books of 60-70s.

Comment: Sodium is the *easiest* element to be determined by very economical instruments called flame photometers. There are no titrimetric methods for sodium as far as I know. Only gravimetric methods exist and they will require the skill of a highly trained analytical chemist! Consult the classic book called Applied Inorganic Analysis by Hillebrand. It should be available from Internet Archive.